# Как сделать редирект с главной страницы поддомена (r.site.com) на главную домена (site.com)

Tags: .htaccess

Информации по редиректу тут много, а простого ответа на этот  вопрос не нашел.

Comment: `subdomain` - это наименование поддомена, в вашем случае это `r`

Answer (score 1):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.subdomain\.site\.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.site\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://site.com/$1 [R=301,NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: **Alex**Не вижу в коде поддомен (в данном случае r.site.com).А если есть необходимость перенаправить скажем два поддомена? Непонятно.

Comment: напишите пожалуйста под нашим ответом в комментарии, что именно Вам непонятно, `subdomain` - это наименование поддомена, в вашем случае это `r`, т.е. `www\.subdomain\.site\.com` - это `www\.r\.site\.com`

Comment: **Alex** Все работает, спасибо за полный ответ.

Comment: @Евгений рады помочь. Однако помните, что комментарии предназначены для уточнения ответа, а не слов благодарности. [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Если ответ Вам помог, пожалуйста не забудьте отметить ответ как решение(галка под стрелкой цифры слева от ответа), чтобы Ваш вопрос не остался открытым.